# Unrelated RxJS observable causes Apollo subscription to trigger multiple times on ngOnInit

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, apollo

I have a music application that needs to load an album (I call it a submission) and a comments section. I've run in to a weird issue that when I create a `comments$` observable, it causes the `submission$` observable to trigger twice on initial page load. Here's my process in debugging. Can anyone explain what is happening?

**Note:** I posted this on the Apollo spectrum chat with no luck, and I've added an update at the bottom.

In my `ngOnInit()` I have the following two queries:

```
// to load the submission
this.submission$ = this.submissionGQL.watch({
  id: this.submissionId
}).valueChanges.pipe(
  takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe),
  map(submission => {
    console.log(submission)
    const sub = submission.data.submission;
    sub.releaseDate = moment.utc(moment.unix(parseInt(sub.releaseDate))).format("MMM DD, YYYY");
    sub.proof = new URL(sub.proof || "https://releasehub.co").hostname;
    return sub;
  }),
  shareReplay(1)
);

// to load all the comments for that submission
this.comments$ = this.paginatedCommentsGQL.watch(
  {
    cursor: this.cursor,
    limit: this.limit,
    submissionId: this.submissionId
  }
).valueChanges.pipe(
  takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe),
  tap((response) => {
    this.cursor = response.data.paginatedComments.response_metadata.next_cursor;
  }),
  map((response) => {
    return response.data.paginatedComments.comments
  })
)
```

I use these observables with async pipes in my Angular HTML like so:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="submission$ | async as submission; else loading">
<!-- submission code here -->
</ng-container>

<app-comment *ngFor="let comment of comments$ | async" [comment]="comment"></app-comment>
```

However, on page load I've noticed this causes `submission$` to trigger twice (I've added a console log in the map() pipe of the submission:

[image: Screen Shot 2020-01-07 at 9.49.58 PM.png]

...but when I remove the `comments$` observable, everything runs just fine. So this led me to believe that the comments query was causing the cache to update something that the `submission$` query is using. Sure enough, when I marked the `fetchPolicy` of the `comments$` as `no-cache`, the query didn't trigger twice. But this got me curious as to what was causing the double trigger.. Both graphql queries return some information about users, so I thought maybe that was the issue. Here is what is returned from both queries, I've commented sections that relate to users:

Submission:

```
query Submission($id: Int) {
    submission(id: $id) {
        id
        artistID
        title
        artists {
            id,
            name,
            imageURL,
            artistUID
        },
        hunter {  // this is a single user
            id,
            imageURL,
            username
        },
        contributors { // this is an array of users
            id,
            imageURL,
            username
        }
    }
}
```

Comment:

```
query PaginatedComments($cursor: String, $limit: Int, $submissionId: Int) {
    paginatedComments(cursor: $cursor, limit: $limit, submissionId: $submissionId) {
        response_metadata {
          next_cursor
        }
        comments {
            id,
            userID,
            content,
            createdAt,
            user { // single user, aka the commentor
                id,
                username,
                imageURL
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So to test my theory, I removed the the `user` response from `PaginatedComments` but this still caused the cache to retrigger.

On my next test, I placed the `comments$` query in a `setTimeout` of 3 seconds after page load. Interestingly, this did not cause the `submission$` to retrigger like it would if `comments$` was loaded on page load. WEIRD.

My next experiment was to reconfigure the results of the `comments$` query in to a `BehaviorSubject`, like so:

```
commentsSubject = new BehaviorSubject([]);
comments$ = this.commentsSubject.asObservable();

this.paginatedCommentsQuery.valueChanges.pipe(
  tap((response) => {
    this.cursor = response.data.paginatedComments.response_metadata.next_cursor;
  }),
  map((response) => {
    this.commentsSubject.next(response.data.paginatedComments.comments)
  })
)
```

Doing the above to load comments, does not cause the `submission$` observable to retrigger. So strange. Anyone have any thoughts as to why the initial methods at the top of this post are causing the `submission$` to trigger twice? I've tried my best to debug myself but I've hit my boundary (i think) on how far I can debug on my side. Thanks!

I'm using `apollo-angular: ^1.7.0`

---

Update! So I kind of understand why doing this in my `map()` pipe would cause the observable to retrigger:

```
sub.releaseDate = moment.utc(moment.unix(parseInt(sub.releaseDate))).format("MMM DD, YYYY");
sub.proof = new URL(sub.proof || "https://releasehub.co").hostname;
```

since I'm changing the value...BUT why is this only happening when `comments$` exists on page load as well? That's what puzzles me. I would still like to know the answer, but for now, I took the better(?) approach, and added angular `pipes` that do the text transformations on both `releaseDate` (releaseDate | formatDate) and `proof` (proof | shortURL) that I need.